# How do I convert string type data to integer type data from firebase database in ios & swift language

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, casting

Now I'm struggling with convert string type data into integer type data and calculate in swift language. Now it is possible to bring the data from the firebase Realtime database but when I get off from "code a" part then the value is gone. And another problem is to bring two string type data from firebase Realtime database and convert them into integer to use minus calculation. And the final goal is to show the result of the calculation. I already try to fix the error by double click the error message. But I can't solve the problem. Please give me the answer to solve the problem.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MainViewController:UIViewController{

   var dbRef : DatabaseReference?
   var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle?

   override func viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

      dbRef = Database.database().reference()

      var getData = [String]()
      var data = [String]()
      var calDate = 0

  // code a -------
     databaseHandle = dbRef?.child("bluetooth_No").observe(.childAdded,with: 
{ (snapshot) in //code
           let now = snapshot.value as? String

           if let actualData = now {
               getData.append(actualData)
           }
      }) 
  // code a------

      calData = Int(getData[2]) - Int(getData[3]) //This line is the error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code calculation done before data received from firebase, because firebase observers are async.

so do calculation after you get data from firebase.
please check below code, may it help you.

```
databaseHandle = dbRef?.child("bluetooth_No").observe(.childAdded,with:
{ (snapshot) in //code
    let now = snapshot.value as? String

    if let actualData = now {
        getData.append(actualData)
    }
    if getData.count > 3{
        calData = Int(getData[2])! - Int(getData[3])!
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks to your help!